# Livereload of sources using Gruntjs

Tags: gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-watch

I am not able to get live reloading running. Grunt is not reporting any issues. The web mockup is running at MAMP port 8888, not sure if this information is important to solve this problem.

The CSS resource is not loaded at all

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//localhost:1111/style/style.css">
```

Here is my Gruntjs.file

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    paths: ["style"],
                    compress: true,
                    yuicompress: true,
                    optimization: 2
                },
                files: {
                    "style/style.css": "source/style/style.less"
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            less: {
                files: "source/style/*",
                tasks: ["less"],
                options: {
                    nospawn: true
                }
            },
            css: {
                files: ['style/style.css'],
                options: {
                    livereload: 1111
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

How can I check if the reload service is running correctly?

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you watching css? You might also want to update you watch task for less to `['less:development']`

Comment: Did you put a [corresponding script](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/docs/watch-examples.md#enabling-live-reload-in-your-html) into your files? Though I'm not sure if it's supposed to work with a MAMP servers at all.

Comment: I made it working (see my answer), however it does not always reloads the page. I am getting mad. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution. I downloaded Chrome LiveReload extension and everything works now. Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    paths: ["style"],
                    compress: true,
                    yuicompress: true,
                    optimization: 2
                },
                files: {
                    "style/style.css": "source/style/style.less"
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            less: {
                files: "source/style/*",
                tasks: ["less"],
                options: {
                    nospawn: true
                }
            },
            css: {
                files: ['style/style.css'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```